# Function that takes a function with any number of arguments and returns a function with the same arguments

Tags: typescript

There have been similar questions to this one already, but none that I feel fully answer this question.

What I'm trying to create is a function that takes another function with any number and type of arguments, but a known return type, performs a modification, and returns a function with those same arguments and return type.

As an example of how this would look, if I had an interface A and function B that takes a string and an object:

```
interface A<T extends string>{
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: T
}

function B<T extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: {a: string, b: number}): A<T>{
  return {...arg2, c: arg1}
}
```

I want a function that could take function B, or any other function with varying arguments that returns interface A, and perform a modification and then return a function with the same arguments.

My first approach was something like this. It's been simplified for this question:

```
function C<T extends string>(func: () => A<T>,arg2: T): () => A<T>;
function C<T extends string, U>(func: (args: U) => A<T>, arg2: T): (args: U) => A<T>;
function C<T extends string, U>(func: (args: U) => A<T>, arg2: T): (args: U) => A<T>{
  return (args: U) => {
    const original = func(args)
    const modified = {...original, c: arg2}
    return modified
  };
}
```

But it doesn't accept a function with multiple arguments, which makes sense:

```
const D = C(B, "Hello World")
/*No overload matches this call.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(func: () => A<string>, arg2: string): () => A<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: { a: string; b: number; }) => A<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => A<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(func: (args: unknown) => A<string>, arg2: string): (args: unknown) => A<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: { a: string; b: number; }) => A<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(args: unknown) => A<string>'.*/
```

I tried using `...rest`, but that didn't work either:

```
function C<T extends string>(func: () => A<T>,arg2: T): () => A<T>;
function C<T extends string, U>(func: (...args: U[]) => A<T>, arg2: T): (...args: U[]) => A<T>;
function C<T extends string, U>(func: (...args: U[]) => A<T>, arg2: T): (...args: U[]) => A<T>{
  return (...args: U[]) => {
    const original = func(...args)
    const modified = {...original, c: arg2}
    return modified
  };
}

const D = C(B, "Hello World")
/*No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(func: () => A<string>, arg2: string): () => A<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: { a: string; b: number; }) => A<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => A<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(func: (...args: unknown[]) => A<string>, arg2: string): (...args: unknown[]) => A<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends string>(arg1: T, arg2: { a: string; b: number; }) => A<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: unknown[]) => A<string>'.
      Types of parameters 'arg1' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.*/
```

I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible. Any help will definitely be appreciated.

Comment: On the face of it, you just want to use `U extends any[]` and `(...args: U) => ...`, and it will let you call `C(B, "Hello World")`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq82qN).  But then you immediately run into problems with higher order function manipulation that the compiler just can't do; `D` is inferred to be a function type with `any` in it in places you want to see `"Hello World"`.  There's no full type unification in TS (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)), and the higher-order function stuff introduced in TS3.4 doesn't cover this case.

Comment: I can write up an answer saying as much, but I'm not sure if your question is primarily about resolving your compiler error (in which case, the example code in the question should have that higher order stuff removed), or about the full unification issues (in which case, the example code in the question should just start off with `U extends any[]`).

Comment: That actually worked perfectly for me. For me, the problem was that I wanted to retain type information for the arguments of function D, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I think that my mistake was to assume that U already extended any. With my specific code, it actually is inferring the correct return type for D.

Comment: Are you sure?  The type that comes out will let you call `C(B, "Hello World")("Goodbye World", { a: "", b: 1 });` and the `"Goodbye World"` should rightfully be an error.  If this works perfectly for you then maybe we can change your example code to something like this: [link to code](https://tsplay.dev/NBzKdN)?

Comment: I see what you're saying. I think I simplified my example code too much, and missed some important things. Let me see if I can do better...

Comment: Here's a version closer to what my code does: [link](https://tsplay.dev/mbkp2W)